# c# Delete label after create programmatically

Tags: c#, label

I use the code below to create multiple new label on panel1 when i search on database. Any chance to remove the label if i delete one name on my database?

```
public void labelLocate(string name, string labelLocate, int x, int y)
{
    // name is the ID in the database
    var label = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == name);
    if (label != null) this.Controls.Remove(label);
    Label labelstring = new Label();
    labelstring.Width = 0;
    labelstring.Text = name;
    labelstring.Name = name;            
    labelstring.AutoSize = true;
    this.Controls.Remove(labelstring);
    this.Controls.Add(labelstring);
    labelstring.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    labelstring.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    labelstring.BringToFront();

    switch (labelLocate)
    {
        case "Up": labelstring.Location = new Point(x + (panel1.Location.X + 3), (y - 20) + (panel1.Location.Y + 3));
            break;
        case "Down": labelstring.Location = new Point(x + (panel1.Location.X + 3), (y) + 5 + (panel1.Location.Y + 3));
            break;
        case "Left": labelstring.Location = new Point(x - 5 - (labelstring.Width) + (panel1.Location.X + 3), y + 5 + (panel1.Location.Y + 3));
            break;
        case "Right": labelstring.Location = new Point(x + 10 + (panel1.Location.X + 3), y + 5 + (panel1.Location.Y + 3));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense (imho) to add [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27897948/284240) at the top of the method. Why do you want to remove the control before  you add it? You want to remove it when the item was deleted in the database, so you should put it at the end of that method.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter My program was able to add/delete/edit the "ID", so when i update on my database i have to call this code to check the ID. If ID valid then create new label, else delete those i have create before. I have try to put in at the end of the code but its still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ControlCollection.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and LINQ:

```
var label = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "TheID");
if(label != null)
    this.Controls.Remove(label);
```

Comment: Have try this method before. After i delete the "ID" in my database, the label was still there.

Comment: @JefferyLR: you have to call this code yourself when you delete it in the database. It doesn't run automatically. Also, _what_ code have you tried before, have you tried _this_ code?

Comment: Yes, i did run the subroutine again after i delete it in the database.

Comment: @JefferyLR: but in the code that you have posted now in your question you are using my code _before_ you add that control. That's pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Find your cotrol and then:

```
if(label != null)
          label.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hi, @cristi Roman. The problem is how to find my control by the time i create the label programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a label more easily using this code:

`this.Controls.Remove(label1);`.

`this` is a current form. `Controls` is a labels, buttons, etc. located on form. `Remove()` removes the target control.